# Странное поведение при повторной отрисовке прямоугольника в классе JS

Tags: javascript, ооп, canvas

Первый раз пытаюсь работать с ООП, пытаюсь создать класс который будет рисовать на canvas. Почему при повторном выполнении метода drawRect() прямоугольник рисуется на половину canvas? Объясните это странное поведение.

Ссылка на codepen: https://codepen.io/ilyacnt/pen/KKZzzRL

```js
class CanvasRenderer {
  canvasElement = null;
  canvasWidth = 0;
  canvasHeight = 0;
  ctx = null;

  constructor(canvasElement) {
    this.canvasElement = canvasElement;
    this.ctx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
    this.canvasHeight = canvasElement.height;
    this.canvasWidth = canvasElement.width;
  }

  clear() {
    this.ctx.rect(0, 0, this.canvasHeight, this.canvasWidth);
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    this.ctx.fill();
  }
}

class Brush extends CanvasRenderer {
  currentFillColor = "black";

  constructor(canvasElement) {
    super(canvasElement);
  }

  set fillColor(color) {
    this.currentFillColor = color;
  }

  drawRect() {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.currentFillColor;
    this.ctx.rect(450, 300, 50, 50);
    this.ctx.fill();
  }
}

const canvasElement = document.getElementById("canvas");
const brush = new Brush(canvasElement);

brush.drawRect();
brush.clear();
brush.drawRect();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прямоугольник рисуется на всю ширину и всю высоту, потому что в `CanvasRenderer.clear()` создаётся контур прямоугольника ([`rect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rect)), который заливается в последующих вызовах `fill`.

Перед новой заливкой ([`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fill)) или выделения контуров ([`stroke`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/stroke)) нужно вызвать [`beginPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath), чтобы эти действия применялись к ожидаемым очертаниям:

```js
class CanvasRenderer {
  canvasElement = null;
  canvasWidth = 0;
  canvasHeight = 0;
  ctx = null;

  constructor(canvasElement) {
    this.canvasElement = canvasElement;
    this.ctx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
    this.canvasHeight = canvasElement.height;
    this.canvasWidth = canvasElement.width;
  }

  clear() {
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.rect(0, 0, this.canvasHeight, this.canvasWidth);
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    this.ctx.fill();
  }
}

class Brush extends CanvasRenderer {
  currentFillColor = "black";

  constructor(canvasElement) {
    super(canvasElement);
  }

  set fillColor(color) {
    this.currentFillColor = color;
  }

  drawRect() {
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.currentFillColor;
    this.ctx.rect(450, 300, 50, 50);
    this.ctx.fill();
  }
}

const canvasElement = document.getElementById("canvas");
const brush = new Brush(canvasElement);

brush.drawRect();
brush.clear();
brush.drawRect();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="600"></canvas>
```

Также можно использовать готовые решения для заливки ([`fillRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect)) и очистки ([`clearRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect)) прямоугольников:

```js
class CanvasRenderer {
  canvasElement = null;
  canvasWidth = 0;
  canvasHeight = 0;
  ctx = null;

  constructor(canvasElement) {
    this.canvasElement = canvasElement;
    this.ctx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
    this.canvasHeight = canvasElement.height;
    this.canvasWidth = canvasElement.width;
  }

  clear() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvasHeight, this.canvasWidth);
  }
}

class Brush extends CanvasRenderer {
  currentFillColor = "black";

  constructor(canvasElement) {
    super(canvasElement);
  }

  set fillColor(color) {
    this.currentFillColor = color;
  }

  drawRect() {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.currentFillColor;
    this.ctx.fillRect(450, 300, 50, 50);
  }
}

const canvasElement = document.getElementById("canvas");
const brush = new Brush(canvasElement);

brush.drawRect();
brush.clear();
brush.drawRect();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Сделал метод clearRect как на втором примере. Очищается область canvas только 600x600, а остальное нет. Хотя я четко передаю в clearRect(0, 0, 600, 900)

Comment: А все исправил, перепутал местами ширину и высоту

Comment: @IlyaB. Если ответ Вам помог, то ставьте галочку рядом с ответом, чтобы его [принять](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)